# NSOperationQueue background process in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am new in NSOperationQueue, I need to call web-service in background process using NSOperationQueue, how to do that, please help me.
I have spend more time for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post the code where you have tried to solve this issue your self.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSOperationQueue with a timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862771/nsoperationqueue-with-a-timer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the OperationQueue-Part try

```
NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] initWithBlock:^{
//your code here
//and here ;)
}];
```

It will start automatically. For more on OperationQueues, look at the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some [good tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) and guides on the topic, even in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1). Use the search function more, or you'll get a lot of downvotes for asking trivial questions.